# how to monitor from each other in two services

Tags: android

There are two services running in two different processes. I am using bindservice e.g. A binds B, but when B has been created, how to bind A from B so B can be notified when A or its process has been destroyed??

Thanks

Comment: can you please explain in details. I think you want to start service B from serviceA and if service B is completed then you want to start Service A is it?

Comment: No. The purpose why I am asking is because I don't want my service( called A)  or process where the A resides to be killed, e.g. running permanently if needed. So there I think to use another service B to bind and create service A. So far there is no problem and B will get notified in onServiceDisconnected once A is destroyed. So likewise, to keep B alive, I bind B in A, but the problem is:

Comment: I can't bind B because B is already running and I am not able to know when the B is killed. So is there anyway to achieve this?